# Can I create a django widget which posts back the form on a mobile?

Tags: django, forms, mobile, widget

I would like to create a widget for use in Django Forms. There is a problem though: i don't know how to make it properly work on a mobile. I'm wanting to create something like this:

Send message to: *search-box-here* **search**

and pressing search will post the page, but not actually submit the form at all. instead the widget will perform a search of friends, and return them in a list like this:

Send message to: *search-box-here* **search**

*Add Person* Bob Smith

*Add Person* John Smith

Does anyone know how I would get the bare-bones of doing this. I know I can do this with javascript, but most mobile web browser do not support JavaScript at all, never mind any AJAX tech.

Joe

Comment: You can't do AJAX without the J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile browsers are so limited, look at how gmail does it for example. It shows you top 10 recent recipients and text box to search for others.

Comment: How do i do this with django forms?

Comment: i would have a form with ModelChoiceField for "top recipients" and charfield for searching. On page submit check if anything in choice field was checked OR (if none) do a search by text and put results into choice field again. There's nothing special about the form but the logic behind it in view.

Comment: and i would just not validate the form?

Comment: why not? if there are no input in textfield and checked items in choice field - i think that tells you that user selected recipients

Comment: I've actually made it work properly how I want. I've just subclassed the Form class and like added magic to the fields. :)